# NetLogo - Create functions that affect landscape equally

Tags: netlogo

I have a NetLogo model for which I'd like to create different human disturbance scenarios impacting carnivore "prey" across the landscape. Here is my NetLogo landscape of a real protected area. Lighter colored pixels have higher prey values than darker colored pixels. [image]

I'd like to create functions that simulate human disturbance from the edge of the protected area. I'd like to try different functions, such as sigmoidal and exponential decay (i.e., areas closer to edge of protected area have prey pixel values reduced more so than prey pixels farther from the edge). [image]

I can implement some simple functions with the following:

```
ask patches with [is-park?] ; patches inside the protected area
[
set dist-boundary distance (min-one-of patches with [is-park? = FALSE][distance myself]) ; calculate distance of patch from edge of park
set prey (prey - e ^ (- dist-boundary / 10)) ; scenario 1 human disturbance
set prey (prey - (-0.1 * dist-boundary ^ 2 + 0.9 * dist-boundary)) ; scenario 2 human disturbance
]
```

However, I'd ideally like to create a set of scenarios such that the total prey reduction across the landscape is equal for each scenario (but distributed across the landscape differently). That would allow me to assess the impact of spatial distribution of human disturbance independent of total magnitude of impact. Any ideas on how to do that would help me a bunch. I've been stuck on this a while now.

Comment: user2359494, this seems like more of a mathematical question than a NetLogo question.  You don't seem to have difficulty implementing mathematical functions in NetLogo.  Rather, you have a set of requirements, and you're looking for a set of mathematical functions that satisfy those requirements.  I would suggest formulating the requirements a little a bit more abstractly, and then ask a question on math.stackexchange.  I think that what you're looking for is a set of functions that, among other things, have the same integral across the landscape ("total prey reduction ... is equal").

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the "diffuse" function.

```
diffuse "patch-variable" "number"
```

When you have a human (possibly a turtle) in a patch they can diffuse "negative-influence" a patch variable double I just invented that would remove prey and decrease as it does so.

```
    ask patches with [human?] ;patches with a human create negative influence
     [
      set negative-influence 8.8; can be any number
     ]
```

So you've created negative-influence now we implement the diffusion:

```
   ask patches with [negative-influence>1]
    [ 
        set prey prey-(factor*negative-influence); removes some prey
        set negative-influence negative-influence*(1-factor); reduce negative-influence
        diffuse negative-influence 0.5 ; half gets diffused into neighboring patches
    ]
```